# Recurring contributions - line items - quantity set equal to amount, should be 1

Tags: recurring-contributions, line-items

I think I've found a bug with recurring contributions in 5.71.1. Reproducible in sandbox running 5.73.alpha1.

1. Create a recurring contribution for $15
2. View the contribution created

Should see line item that says Quantity = 1, Amount = $15.

But I see Quantity = 15, Amount = $15.

Comment: Just tried to replicate on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/ but i see correct Qty number 1, and not 15. Can you add more steps to replicate?

Comment: Hi @jitendra-fuzion I tried using that Demo and observed the correct behaviour. I tried going back to the sandbox I used (https://demo.circle-interactive.co.uk) but it is running 5.71.1 and doesn't have the problem. Hmmm. Suspect I was hallucinating!

Answer (score 0):

I had reproduced this issue on a sandbox, but after prompting by @jitendra-fuzion I'm now unable to reproduce this on either the sandbox I used or the Demo Jitendra suggested. The issue must be with my local configuration.